# Cancel Infragistics UltraGrid cell click event

Tags: vb.net, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I want to cancel the cell click but I don't find an **e.Cancel** or similar. How is this done in the UltraWinGrid?

```
 Private Sub ugResult_ClickCell(sender As System.Object, e As Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.ClickCellEventArgs) Handles ugResult.ClickCell
        If Not IsDBNull(currentUser) Then
            // some code
        Else
            // e.Cancel or similar ???
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Don't think it is possible to cancel the event. What specifically do you want to prevent with cancelling the event, the edit action?

Comment: @Steve only certain users should be able to edit certain rows - not all. That is why I cannot just disable the editing on the whole column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking to make the Grid read only or not allow editing for a specific user you could look at the following:

- [Disable a Band or the Entire WinGrid](http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/WinForms/Current/CLR4.0/?page=WinGrid_Disable_a_Band_or_the_Entire_WinGrid.html) in the [Editing Data](http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/WinForms/Current/CLR4.0/?page=WinGrid_Editing_Data.html) section of the help.
- Changing the [CellClickAction](http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/WinForms/Current/CLR4.0/?page=Infragistics4.Win.UltraWinGrid.v13.1~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridOverride~CellClickAction.html) to CellSelect or RowSelect rather than Edit or EditAndSelectText.

If you wish to prevent editing conditionally for certain cells, the [BeforeEnterEditMode](http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/WinForms/Current/CLR4.0/?page=Infragistics4.Win.UltraWinGrid.v13.1~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGrid~BeforeEnterEditMode_EV.html) event can be canceled.